# Changing active directory user password with dsmod

Tags: active-directory

On windows Server 2016,i try to change a an active directory password with dsmod.

```
DSMOD user "cn=xxxxxxxx,cn=users,dc=xxxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxxx" -pwd xxxxxxxx -mustchpwd yes
```

i have the message "objet de l'annuaire non trouvé" (i guess: "object of directory not found")

if i try to add the account with dsadd :

```
DSADD user "cn=xxxxxxxxxx,cn=users,dc=xxxxxxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxxxxx" -pwd xxxxxxxxxx -display xxxxxxxxxx -desc "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

i have the message "le compte spécifié existe déjà" (i guess: "account specified already exists")

What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

•   The command that you are using for modifying the password of a user in AD is correct as per the official documentation for this command. But please ensure that you are executing this command from the powershell with elevated privileges, specifically with domain administrator’s credentials as you are modifying the AD attributes for a specific user.

•   Secondly, please ensure that the path of the user object in AD for which you want to change the password has been copied from Active Directory Site and Interfaces management portal, i.e., ADSI edit interface as it gives the correct DN (distinguished name) for that object in AD. This will ensure that the exact and perfect DN is used for the object for which password is to be changed. It will not leave any ambiguity there for any other likewise user object existing amidst other AD user objects.

•   Next, I would suggest you to please check whether AD replication ports are open or not, i.e., TCP UDP 135, 137, 138, 139, 445, 389, 636, 3268, 3269, 88, 53, 1512, 42, 49152-65535. These ports are associated with various services regarding AD, viz., RPC Endpoint mapper, DNS< WINS resolution, replication, RPC dynamic ports, etc. Ensure that these are reachable from the server system through which you are trying to execute the command.

•   Lastly, please check the server system’s logs regarding this issue to see whether any event or input for this is captured or not. Please check the official documentation link below for command execution related arguments: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc732954(v=ws.11)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc731279(v=ws.11)